# How to direct excel if statement outputs to new cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am writing an equation sheet that helps me convert units and then uses those numbers in other more complex equations. I would like to input a value in inches then have it output in feet in the same table. That part is easy. The part I am struggling with is in the same table I would like the option to input feet and have it return inches where I would normally type it. I know I will need another table with all my if statements. more just wondering if excel even has this ability within the IF function please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I would have a cell A1, for the input to choose "In" or "Ft", then you can have if() choose between the two conversion calculations like so: =if(A1="In",B1*12,if(A1="Ft",B1,"error")) assuming B1 has the number and the if() is in cell C1.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a `Convert()` worksheet function especially for this need. In order to convert a number from inch to feet, you can do the following:

```
=CONVERT(A1,"in","ft")
```

In order to find out how it works, just type `=CONVERT(` and a helper box (intellisense) will be opened for helping you to fill in the proper parameters.

Comment: that works for basic units. But what I need to do is to convert angular accelerations and then using those number versus a gear ratio to find out put speed torque and inertia required to turn said gear